# Output what commands a rake task is executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I just want to better understand how some of the built in `rake` tasks are operating, in particular `rake db:create`.

Is there a way I can view the sql commands being executed to create the database?  I tried `rake db:create --verbose --trace`, but all I got was

```
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute (dry run) db:load_config
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute (dry run) rails_env
** Execute (dry run) db:create
```

I'm running rails 3.2.13 and rake 10.0.4

Comment: Isn't easier to look in the source code of the tasks? I don't think rake will provide you anything better than --trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom rake task which will do require task given below

```
desc "Rake db:create with SQL logging"
task :db_create => :environment do
  Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
  `rake db:create`
end
```

It will gives your required output.